# GDB on CentOS ignores gdbinit file

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

When I run program in GDB/CentOS, I see following message in console:

```
warning: File "/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
```

I do exactly what this warning says. I create file `/home/user/.gdbinit` with the only line `add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py`. Nothing changed. I see the same error message even after restart.
Are there any ideas what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [gdb docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading-safe-path.html):

> ```
> set auto-load safe-path [directories]
> ```
>
> Set the list of directories (and their subdirectories) trusted for automatic loading and execution of scripts.

This is to specifiy directories, but you specify a file:

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18-gdb.py
```

You might want to do:

```
add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/lib64/
```

Comment: I updated my .gdbinit file, however, nothing changed. Is it possible somehow to check whether GDB reads this file at all?

Comment: @VASoftOnline: If you'd have read the fine manual (I linked), you might have stumbled over this: `show auto-load safe-path: Show the list of directories trusted for automatic loading and execution of scripts.`.

Comment: Well, you right, so, when I make `show auto-load safe-path`, it outputs `$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load:/usr/lib64/`. So it reads this file and has `/usr/lib64` in autoload path. But why does it show warning if everything is ok?